# Planning website/application for my game

Tags: game-development, planning

I'm making a game, but before I start, i wanna plan everything. Is there a website or an application for Mac to plan your game. I was looking for something like this:
[image]

Thank you. [Picture Link](http://s657.photobucket.com/user/pscion/media/plantree.gif.html)

Comment: What you are searching is a mindmap software. Check wikipedia for concrete realizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/). It supports all UML type diagram and you can use activity diagram. Here is sample of activity diagram:

[image]

Short about UMLet:

> UMLet is a free, open-source UML tool with a simple user interface:
>   draw UML diagrams fast, build sequence and activity diagrams from
>   plain text, export diagrams to eps, pdf, jpg, svg, and clipboard,
>   share diagrams using Eclipse, and create new, custom UML elements.
>   UMLet runs stand-alone or as Eclipse plug-in on Windows, OS X and
>   Linux.